# Prove that $\det(\overline M)=\overline {\det(M)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For $M \in M_{n×n}(\mathbb C)$ , let $\overline M$ be the matrix such that $(\overline M)_{ij}=\overline {M_{ij}}$ for all $i,j$, where $\overline {M_{ij}}$ is the complex conjugate of $M_{ij}$.

> Prove that $\det(\overline M)=\overline {\det(M)}$.

My attempt: We will use induction on $n$.

Base case $n=1$: Let $M$ be the one-by-one matrix with entry $a+bi$
\begin{align*}
\det(\overline M) &= \det(a-bi)=a-bi \\
\overline {\det(M)} &=\overline {a+bi}=a-bi
\end{align*}

Induction hypothesis: assume holds for $n$, NTS it holds for $n+1$:

\begin{align*}
\det(\overline M) &= \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} {(-1)^{1+j} \overline M_{1j} \cdot \det(\overline {\tilde M_{1j}}})
\\&=(-1)^{1+n+1} \overline {M_{1,n+1}}\cdot \det(\overline {\tilde M_{1,n+1})} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} {(-1)^{1+j} \overline M_{1j} \cdot \det(\overline {\tilde M_{1j}}})
\\&=(-1)^{2+n}\overline {M_{1,n+1}}\cdot \overline{\det(\tilde M_{1,n+1})}+\overline{\det(M')}
\end{align*}
where $M'$ is $n$-by-$n$. I feel like the proof is almost complete but am not sure how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I like your proof

Comment: Instead of separating the last summand you should just use $\det\left(\overline{\tilde M_{1j}}\right) = \overline{\det\left(\tilde M_{1j}\right)}$, which holds by induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the recursive definition of the determinant given by
$$ \det(a) = a$$
for $1\times 1$ matrices $(a)$ and
$$ \det(A) = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} a_{1,j} \, \det\left( A_{1,j}\right), $$
where $A=(a_{ij})$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with $n>1$ and $A_{1,j}$ is the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix obtained from $A$ by removing the first row and the $j$-th column.

(I use a different notation since I find $\tilde A_{1,j}$ referring to a submatrix and $A_{1,j}$ referring to an entry rather confusing.)

When $B=\overline A$ with entries $b_{ij}=\overline{a_{ij}}$ you already proved that $\det(B)=\det(A)$ in case $n=1$.

For $n>1$ we get: $$\det(B) = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} b_{1,j} \, \det\left( B_{1,j}\right).$$
Note that $b_{1,j}=\overline{a_{1,j}}$ and $B_{1,j}=\overline{A}_{1,j}=\overline{A_{1,j}}$, since it doesn't matter wether you first conjugate and then remove rows/columns or first remove rows/columns and then conjugate.

Hence, $$\det(B) = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} \overline{a_{1,j}} \, \det\left( \overline{A_{1,j}}\right).$$

Since $A_{1,j}$ is an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix, we can assert by induction hypothesis that $\det(\overline{A_{1,j}}) = \overline{\det(A_{1,j})}$ so that
$$\det(B) = \sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} \overline{a_{1,j}} \, \overline{\det\left( A_{1,j}\right)}.$$

Since conjugation is compatible with multiplication and addition ($\overline z + \overline w = \overline{z+w}$ and $\overline z \cdot \overline w = \overline{z\cdot w})$, we get
$$\det(B) = \overline{\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{1+j} a_{1,j} \, \det\left( A_{1,j}\right)} = \overline{\det(A)}.$$

---

Note that there is no need to separate the last summand at any time. You might have guessed so since proving summation formulas often involves separating one summand to apply the induction hypothesis, but here we are not proving a summation formula. We are merely *using* one. The induction is on the size of the matrix which just happens to be the number of summands, but $A_{1,j}$ is already an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix in *all* the $n$ summands.

Answer (score 4):

The above approach should work but working with such an iterative description of the determinant is just annoying.

Hopefully, you know the following result/definition of the determinant:

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, then $$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^na_{i,\sigma(i)}.$$

Indeed, if $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, the above formula reduces to the expression $ad-bc$.

Anyhow, once you have this description, note that
$$\det(\overline{A})=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n\overline{a_{i,\sigma(i)}}=\overline{\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^na_{i,\sigma(i)}}=\overline{\det(A)}.$$

Comment: OP is using a perfectly fine definition of the determinant and the question is not about the least annoying definition. OP specifically asked about their own approach to prove the statement.

Comment: @Christoph : I'm not arguing that OP's definition or proof is not valid. I'm arguing that there is a much more elegant approach that is less prone to getting confused because of irrelavent technical details. I'm giving a answer, not **the** answer. If OP is not satisfied with this answer, he/she's free to express that in a comment.

Comment: An alternative proof using alternative definitions is not an answer to the question "How do I proceed with *this* proof?".

Comment: @Christoph : "My attempt: We will use induction on n." I'm saying, don't do that, it's just too much work for the question "Prove that $\det(\overline{M})=\overline{\det(M)}$. I think your lengthy answer actually underlines my point. Nonetheless, your answer is perfectly fine and indeed answers precisely that part of OP's question.

Comment: My answer is lengthy because I explain every single step, not because it involves any technical difficulties.

Comment: As far as alternative definitions are concerned, I don't think such an iterative description is a good definition. In particular, you have to fix an expansion via a fixed row or column and later show that all other ways are equivalent. That's ridiculously involved. It's better to start from a decent definition and get these properties out of that.

Comment: @Christoph: "My answer is lengthy because I explain every single step, not because it involves any technical difficulties." No, but there are too many steps in humble opinion. Don't get me wrong, I commend you for taking the time to write it down and help OP. I simply choose to point out an alternative which I think is the more conventional and elegant approach.